# Detect player by specific field of view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on basic AI and would like my AI to detect player by specific field of view. The script it attached on the head of AI and AI does turn its heard with its animator.

I was able to make AI detect player when facing the player directly, but it doesn't feel realistic?

public GameObject Player;
public bool isFacingPlayer;

void Update(){

```
    // check if AI is facing player
    Vector3 dir = Player.transform.position - transform.position;
    if (Vector3.Dot(dir, transform.forward) > 0.0f) {

        isFacingPlayer = true;

    } else {

        isFacingPlayer = false;

    }


}
```

I would like to have a specific field of view, say of 310. But not sure how to get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, I don't really know why I asked for this question if I was able to figure it out on my own with a real logic. Anyways, here's a fix if it'll help anyone:

```
Vector3 targetDir = Player.transform.position - transform.position;
        float angleToPlayer = (Vector3.Angle (targetDir, transform.forward));

        if (angleToPlayer >= -90 && angleToPlayer <= 90) { // 180 FOV
            isFacingPlayer = true;
        } else {
            isFacingPlayer = false;
        }
```

Comment: I know you have resolved your issue but see this answer if you have time https://answers.unity.com/questions/274809/how-to-make-enemy-chase-player-basic-ai.html